# Executing SQL select statements on a remote server using async/await + TPL dataflow: CPU or I/O bound?

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await, remote-access, tpl-dataflow

My `C#` `WinForms` program runs on a `Windows 7` client machine and submits `SELECT` queries to a `SQL Server` instance on a remote server (see DB code snippet below). I think I'm correct in categorizing the code that processes the query results (a series of of `DataTables`) as `CPU bound`, but I'm not confident in how to categorize my DB code (see below) that runs on the client machine. On one hand, its associated with I/O, but I'm thinking that all the I/O resources used are on the remote DB server and handled by the SQL Server instance and not the Win 7 client machine and so even my DB code is `CPU-bound`.

Should I treat/program my DB code that runs on the client machine as `CPU bound` or `I/O bound`? Or, does using `TPL Dataflow` make this point moot?

**My DB Code**

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + MachineName + ReplaceInstanceName + "; Initial Catalog=" + DbName + "; Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=10"))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchString", "%" + userProvidedSearchString + "%");
        sqlCommand.CommandText = queryString;

        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct);
        dataTable_TableDataFromFieldQuery.Load(sqlDataReader);
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The client machine is waiting on a network to deliver results from the SQL server. It's is I/O bound. I/O = any device and really there's not much difference between a disk and a network these days especially when you get to technology like iSCSI or virtualized environments where you may not even know how your 'disk' is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I treat/program my DB code that runs on the client machine as
>   CPU bound or I/O bound

I think the rule of thumb here is if its not in a loop and doing calculations, its probably IO bound. Anything that access a network resource, filesystem or waits for a device to respond is probably IO

More over, not everything in a program consumes CPU time. When a thread tries to read data from a file on disk or sends a TCP/IP packet through network, the only thing it does is delegate the actual work to a device, disk or network adapter, and waits for results.

It’s very expensive to spend a threads’ time on waiting. Even through threads sleep and don’t consume CPU time while waiting for the results, it doesn’t really pay off because it’s a waste of system resources.

Is your request IO? DB's get a little murky however the answer is yes.

*TPL Dataflow* or not, you just don't want to create threads or use resources waiting for IO bound tasks to complete

So the async/await pattern works well or you can use TPL Dataflow block as well. The premise is you don't create huge amounts of tasks that sit there waiting. With `ActionBlock` you can configure the max amount of tasks and reuse them for all the items that meanwhile sit in a buffer waiting for a task.

**Example**

```
var block = new ActionBlock<MySomething>(
    mySomething => MyMethodAsync(mySomething),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 });

foreach (var something in ListOfSomethings)
{
    block.Post(something );
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored on disks on the database server, so the bulk of the IO is going to take place there, where the database engine queries and returns the data to the caller (your application). There will be CPU and memory usage on both ends of the connection until you've retrieved all the batches of data from SQL Server, at which point you'll be operating on those rows in your applications memory.

So your machine isn't taking an IO hit; that's happening where the data lives. However your code is causing IO to occur on the database server, so interpret from that what you will.

Comment: "SQL injection attack": How so? I'm using the `parameters` feature of the `SqlCommand` class. What am I missing?

Comment: Actually I may have jumped the gun there. I saw the name of the parameter and thought it might be accepting a wholesale string of sql to execute, but now I see the wildcard characters around it. It would depend on where `querystring` is set.

Comment: Whew, ok. My queryString is something like: `select fieldX from tableZ where fieldX like @SearchString`